# How do I remove my personal details before publishing my .dotfiles repository to GitHub?

Tags: git, privacy, dotfiles

I want to share my configuration and scripts with the community, but I don't want my personal details (eg email address) out on the World Weird Web to be crawled and spammed.

How do `.dotfiles` publishers remove/redact/hide/expunge/(google search term) their email address and/or other personal details from all their configuration files before `git push`, while still having the files with personal details intact for everyday use?

Especially, how is this done for `.gitconfig` where the personal configuration is required for the push itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put such details into `.gitconfig.local` file which I ignore in my dotfiles repository.

Add this into `~/.gitconfig` to include `.gitconfig.local`

```
[include]
  path = ~/.gitconfig.local
```